# Android "Universal Image Loader" showing very small images sometimes

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using **Universal Image Loader** for downloading Bitmaps and showing them listviews and other Imageviews..Most of the times its working fine, but sometimes it is showing very small Bitmaps compared to their normal size.

I am giving the config values as

`.memoryCacheExtraOptions((int)(screen_width_ * 0.6f),(int)(screen_width_ * 0.6f))`

which sometimes showing very small images....

Please help me get through this...

Comment: please show you `XML`

Comment: This is an Imageview in listview item layout:  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tweetpic_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

Answer (score 1):

Issue is of your ImagSize which is coming from web. 
try this,

`android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Hope it will works !!

Comment: Ok...I will try...As it is happening very rarely, I can't tell now if it works ...Anyway thanks for helping...